# Take a photo using the Android NDK in C++ (no JNI)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm writing a simple NDK application which should take a photo using a camera without having to go via JNI.

I've successfully opened the camera using *ACameraManager_openCamera* and got the camera characteristics (*ACameraManager_getCameraCharacteristics*) but I'm not sure how to take a photo.

All the samples I've found require a *surface* to be be passed from the Java layer. I don't want to do this and want a 100% C++ application using the NDK only.

The app will run on a dedicated rooted device.

Comment: A 100% C++ application without zygote?

Comment: No, I mean using the NDK only in C++  and not using Java/JNI.

Comment: If you want to have no Java/JNI in your app, your process won't be forked with zygote

Comment: OK - but is it possible to take a picture using the NDK (in a native C++ executable) without forking zygote?

Comment: Not in device-independent way. Some phones may support V4L2 out of the box, for other systems you can find some drivers on the Web.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm able to open the camera and everything, but I dont get a callback

Comment: @n0bod1 sadly not. We ended up using a custom C++ camera wrapper supplied by our vendor

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure what you really mean by 100% only C++, but your best bet is to build an app using a Native Activity. https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/native-activity
A github example is at https://github.com/android/ndk-samples, called native activity.

Regarding skipping the surface from Java/Kotlin, your best bet is to use AImageReader https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader (the doc is for the Java version which should be very similar in functionality if not identical to AImageReader). As per my understanding AImageReader allows you to transfer efficiently the image on the CPU side.

based on this demo https://github.com/sixo/native-camera/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp, you can see that you can get a nativewindow from the AImageReader.

```cpp
#ifdef WITH_IMAGE_READER
static void imageCallback(void* context, AImageReader* reader)
{
    AImage *image = nullptr;
    auto status = AImageReader_acquireNextImage(reader, &image);
    LOGD("imageCallback()");
    // Check status here ...

    // Try to process data without blocking the callback
    std::thread processor([=](){

        uint8_t *data = nullptr;
        int len = 0;
        AImage_getPlaneData(image, 0, &data, &len);

        // Process data here
        // ...

        AImage_delete(image);
    });
    processor.detach();
}

AImageReader* createJpegReader()
{
    AImageReader* reader = nullptr;
    media_status_t status = AImageReader_new(640, 480, AIMAGE_FORMAT_JPEG,
                     4, &reader);

    //if (status != AMEDIA_OK)
        // Handle errors here

    AImageReader_ImageListener listener{
            .context = nullptr,
            .onImageAvailable = imageCallback,
    };

    AImageReader_setImageListener(reader, &listener);

    return reader;
}

ANativeWindow* createSurface(AImageReader* reader)
{
    ANativeWindow *nativeWindow;
    AImageReader_getWindow(reader, &nativeWindow);

    return nativeWindow;
}
#endif
```

and

```cpp
ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_create(&outputs);

#ifdef WITH_IMAGE_READER
    imageReader = createJpegReader();
    imageWindow = createSurface(imageReader);
    ANativeWindow_acquire(imageWindow);
    ACameraOutputTarget_create(imageWindow, &imageTarget);
    ACaptureRequest_addTarget(request, imageTarget);
    ACaptureSessionOutput_create(imageWindow, &imageOutput);
    ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_add(outputs, imageOutput);
#endif

    // Create the session
    ACameraDevice_createCaptureSession(cameraDevice, outputs, &sessionStateCallbacks, &textureSession);

    // Start capturing continuously
    ACameraCaptureSession_setRepeatingRequest(textureSession, &captureCallbacks, 1, &request, nullptr);
```

as you can see you can have a full session without any openGL surface, most of the examples use that because it's useful to see the preview on screen but it's not necessary, I guess.

Well, to be honest i haven't tried it, so let us know how it goes :)